# redirect straight after form submission

Tags: php

```
<?php
    require("../inc/global.inc.php");

    if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $checkuser_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
        $checkuser = mysqli_num_rows($checkuser_query);

        if($checkuser>0) {
            die("<div align='center'><div class='indexbody'><h1>Error Message</h1>We couldn't log you in! Press your browsers back button to fix it.<p />");
        }
        else {
            header("Location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Home");
            setcookie("empirebattles",$username,time()+60*60*24*30*365*50);
        }
    }
?>
```

I'm running this code on submission of a loginform. But, it's redirecting me even if the login details are wrong. Any idea why??

Comment: Never store passwords in plain text.  Repeat this with me, *never store passwords in plain text*.  Again, and pay attention this time, ***never store passwords in plain text***.

Comment: change your logic if($checkuser>0) change it to if($checkuser<= 0)

Comment: You should be adding `LIMIT 1` to your query

Comment: Awlad, can you add that as an answer so I can upvote it.

Comment: @user2999920: Yes, you are.  It's obvious from the code that you are.  You compare the user-entered password, unmodified, with the stored password.  This means that the stored password is the user-entered password.  That's the definition of storing passwords in plain text.  It's an absolutely terrible thing to do to your users, and the responsible thing would be to notify your users that you store sensitive information which can potentially be hacked.

Comment: I HAVE POST ANSWER YOU CAN ACCEPT

Comment: David, I removed the encryption method for security.

Comment: Ever heard of ob_start();?

Comment: No need to shout, that's a sign of desperation. @AwladLiton Unless of course, you accidentally spilled coffee on your keyboard ;-)

Comment: @user2999920: `"I removed the encryption method for security"` - A sillier statement has hardly been uttered.  First: Don't "encrypt" passwords.  Hash them.  "Encrypting" them is about as bad as plain text.  Second: "Removing the encryption" doesn't add security, it in fact removes the security provided by the encryption.  (Which isn't much in this case.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($checkuser>0) {
            die("<div align='center'><div class='indexbody'><h1>Error Message</h1>We couldn't log you in! Press your browsers back button to fix it.<p />");
        }
        else {
            header("Location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Home");
            setcookie("empirebattles",$username,time()+60*60*24*30*365*50);
        }
```

change it to:

```
if($checkuser<=0) {
            die("<div align='center'><div class='indexbody'><h1>Error Message</h1>We couldn't log you in! Press your browsers back button to fix it.<p />");
        }
        else {
            header("Location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Home");
            setcookie("empirebattles",$username,time()+60*60*24*30*365*50);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your logic is backward:

```
if($checkuser>0) { // reads "if a user was found"
    // Dies saying "can't log you in"
}
else { // No user is found
    // Redirect
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the condition of the if:

```
if($checkuser==0) {
   die("<div align='center'><div class='indexbody'><h1>Error Message</h1>We couldn't log you in! Press your browsers back button to fix it.<p />");
} else {
   header("Location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Home");
   setcookie("empirebattles",$username,time()+60*60*24*30*365*50);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    require("../inc/global.inc.php");

    if(!empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $username = $_POST["username"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];
        $checkuser_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
        $checkuser = mysqli_num_rows($checkuser_query);

        if($checkuser>0) {
            header("Location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Home");
            setcookie("empirebattles",$username,time()+60*60*24*30*365*50);

        }
        else {
             die("<div align='center'><div class='indexbody'><h1>Error Message</h1>We couldn't log you in! Press your browsers back button to fix it.<p />");
        }
    }
?>
```